# Dealing with SettingWithCopyWarning when assigning columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` which I want to extend with columns that contain data from the previous row.

This script does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 2

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [0,1,1,0,0]}, columns=['A', 'B'])

df2 = df[df['B'] == 0]
print(df2)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    df2['A_%d' % i] = df2['A'].shift(i)

print(df2)
```

It outputs:

```
   A  B
0  1  0
3  4  0
4  5  0

   A  B  A_1  A_2
0  1  0  NaN  NaN
3  4  0  1.0  NaN
4  5  0  4.0  1.0
```

which is exactly what I want. The `DataFrame` now has two additional columns `A_1` and `A_2` that contain the value of column `A` *1* and *2* rows before.

However, I also get the warning:

```
./my_script.py:14: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df2['A_%d' % i] = df2['A'].shift(i)
```

The problem definitely comes from the filtering before where I create `df2`. If I work on `df` directly, the problem does not occur.
In my application I need to work on multiple parts of my original DataFrame separately ant therefore the filtering and is definitely required. All the different parts (like `df2` here) get concatenated later.

I found similar issues in [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) and [Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724378/pandas-settingwithcopywarning) but the solutions from there do not fix the problem.

Writing e.g.

```
df2[:, 'A_%d' % i] = df2['A'].shift(i)
```

the same warning still occurs.

I am working with Python 3.5.2 and Pandas 0.19.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df2 = df[df['B'] == 0].copy()
```

If you modify values in `df2` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: It works. Can you explain why calling `copy()` is required in this case? Especially since the code seems to do fine without it (apart from the warning).

Comment: Explanations are hard for me. Maybe better explain [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38810015/2901002)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I understand now.

Comment: But better it is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39983664/2901002)