# How to filter column by date in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Attempting to filter df to only include rows with date before 2018-11-06.

Column is in datetime format.  Running this code returns only rows with exact date of 2018-11-06 instead of values less than.  Also, when running code with less than symbol '<', only dates later than 2018-11-06 are returned.  It appears that I am doing something very incorrectly.

```py
db4=db3[~(db3['registration_dt']>'2018-11-06')]
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct types. Could you give the output of db3['registration_dt'].dtype?

Comment: Output is datetime64[ns].  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Filter date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904112/pandas-filter-date)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344656/pandas-filter-csv-by-date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Filter CSV by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344656/pandas-filter-csv-by-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are comparing the string '2018-11-06' with a datetime.

```py
import datetime as dt

# Selects all rows where registration date is after 6 november 2018
df = db3[db3['registration_dt']>dt.datetime(2018,11,6)]


# Selects all rows where registration_dt is before 6 november 2018
df = db3[db3['registration_dt']>dt.datetime(2018,11,6)]

# The ~ symbol can be read as not
# This selects all rows before or equal to 6 november 2018
df = db3[~(db3['registration_dt']>dt.datetime(2018,11,6))]
```