# using df.loc[] not returning a view, operation done on same object

Tags: python, pandas

I am having problem with the `.loc[]`

if I do this:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(zip(range(4), range(4)), columns=['a', 'b'])
print(x)
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3

q = x.loc[:, 'a']
q += 2
print(x)
   a  b
0  2  0
1  3  1
2  4  2
3  5  3
```

as you can see my operation on q is done on x also because x.loc[:,'a'] is not returning a copy.

if I do this:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(zip(range(4), range(4)), columns=['a', 'b'])
print(x)
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3

q = x.loc[x.index, 'a']
q += 2
print(x)
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
```

as you can see. doing `x.index` instead of : returns a copy and my operation on q is not reflected on x. I feel like this is very risky am I wondering if this is intended or a bug that : does not behave like x.index

[Jeff answer on .loc with good insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy)
also :
[from the doc](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

thanks for help

**addition on speed:**
of course the : indexer should be much faster than using x.index, which is why I tend to use it:

```
import timeit
%timeit x.loc[:,'a']
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.1 µs per loop
%timeit x.loc[x.index,'a']
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 µs per loop
```