# Updating pandas dataframe row in a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing the following to update a dataframe row:

```
val = "123"
row = df.loc[id, :]
t = type(row['col1'])
val = t(val)
df.loc[id, 'col1'] = val
```

If I do row['col1'] = val, it doesn't update the original dataframe. Is there a way to update the original dataframe without using .loc twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated for comment below*
I believe the short answer is no to

> Is there someway of saying "change the row you've already fetched"

This is because operations in Pandas return a copy not a view to the original DataFrame. There is a StackOverflow post from JeffR who writes much of Pandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy)

If you're trying to assign the `val` to one cell in the DataFrame you can use the `set_value` function. The documentation for that method is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html).

```
val = "123"
row = df.loc[id, :]
t = type(row['col1'])
val = t(val)
df.set_value(id, 'col1', val)
```

If you're trying to assign the `val` with particular data type to all cells in column, can use the apply method

```
def changeType(cell, val):
    # You could pass the id or list of ids as well if you need to perform some logic with it
    t = type(cell)
    cell = t(val)
    return cell

val = "123"
df.loc[:, 'col1'] = df.loc[:, 'col1'].apply(changeType, args=(val,))
```

Comment: df.loc[:, 'col1'] = val would set it for all rows, right? I only want the row matching id to be updated. set_value looks like it'll do what I need, but wouldn't it still require another lookup? Is there someway of saying "change the row you've already fetched", instead of "find row with this id, and change it"?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I better understand what you were trying to ask.