# Python pandas dataframe warning still exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use the following code to create a new column in a dataframe:

```
# data is a dataframe object
data.loc[:,'test'] = 5
```

it comes with the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I already use `.loc[]`, why is there still a warning? Is there any particular point I'm missing in my code? Thanks!

Comment: In general you should be safe here, what you're doing is the correct way to go about this.  But are there any lines _before_ this line that reference or modify `df`?  It is likely that you used chained indexing earlier on in your code and are now modifying in-place on that copy.

Comment: See an example of what I'm talking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy) with the example on querying

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I actually find out I had used chained indexing some lines earlier. By killing this chained indexing problem, now my code works well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [2, 4]], columns=['unit', 'test'])
>>> data
   unit  test
0     1     0
1     2     4
>>> data['test'] = 5
>>> data
   unit  test
0     1     5
1     2     5
>>> data['another_test'] = 6
>>> data
   unit  test  another_test
0     1     5             6
1     2     5             6
```