# Why does .loc/.iloc return a copy and how can I make it return a view Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, view, copy

I have a class containing a `pandas.DataFrame` and a method that returns subset of it's columns. I want to get a view, not a copy.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, path, selected_features):
        df = pandas.read_excel(path)
        self._features = df[selected_features].astype("float64") # df[selected_features] is only int64  and float64

    def features(self):
        return self._features.iloc[, 0:2] # for simplicity let's just return 2 columns
```

Using `np.shares_memory()`I've established that it returns a copy.

```
data = Data(path, selected_features)
print(np.shares_memory(data._features, data.features()))
# False
print(np.shares_memory(data._features, data._features.iloc[:,0:2]))
# False
```

I've tried using `.loc` and it yields the same result.

Why is it returning a copy and how can I make it return a view.

**Note:** I've seen the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960511/pandas-subindexing-dataframes-copies-vs-views), [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy) and [thread 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507799/selecting-a-subset-of-columns-without-copying) - none helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: What is `data._features`?

Comment: Sorry, the class more complex and I tried to leave out the unnecessary parts and made mistakes along the way, which are now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

- `data._features` does not exist in your code, maybe `data.labels`?
- `labels.iloc[0:2]` does not return 2 columns but 2 rows.

> Why does .loc/.iloc return a copy

Or not?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')).copy()

>>> df._is_view
False

>>> df._is_copy
None

>>> hex(id(df))
'0x7fd3c7a5ba60'

>>> df.iloc[:, 0:2]._is_view
True

>>> df.iloc[:, 0:2]._is_copy
<weakref at 0x7fd43731c540; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7fd3c7a5ba60>

>>> np.shares_memory(df, df.iloc[0:2])
True

>>> np.shares_memory(df, df.iloc[0:2].copy())
False
```

Note: `copy()` is important to avoid [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/15239951) because Pandas keeps a reference to the source DataFrame.

Comment: Sorry, the class more complex and I tried to leave out the unnecessary parts and made mistakes along the way, which are now corrected.
Thanks to Your answer I found a mistake in my code - it was in `__init__()`, i added a `.copy()` to line assigning to `self._features` like in Your code and now it works as intended.

Comment: I don't understand why copying  makes a difference though, could You please explain? Please edit Your answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: I updated my answer. I added a link to an interesting Q&A about `copy`.