# Time Series Regression Model Issue

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, regression

I am new to Python trying to do a time series regression model. I have 3 columns, X, Y, and the date. I imported everything below, but I am getting stuck with an error.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 6
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
raw_data = pd.read_csv("IMF and BBG Fair Values.csv")
ISO_TH = raw_data[["IMF_VALUE", "BBG_FV", "IMF_DATE"]]
```

Filtering to get rid of `NaN`:

```
filtered_TH = ISO_TH[np.isfinite(raw_data['BBG_FV'])]
```

I get this error:

> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:2698: >SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

Comment: I actually get the error with this line of code:
    filtered_TH.IMF_DATE = pd.DatetimeIndex(filtered_TH.IMF_DATE)

Comment: import numpy as np
    from sklearn import linear_model
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    %matplotlib inline
    from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
    rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 6
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
    from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
    raw_data=pd.DataFrame([[np.inf,22,333,44], [3,4,5,2],[1,2,3,4],[np.inf,0,0,0]],columns=["BBG_FV", "IMF_VALUE", "IMF_DATE", "unused"])
    ISO_TH = raw_data.loc[:,["IMF_VALUE", "BBG_FV", "IMF_DATE"]]
ISO_TH.IMF_VALUE=[0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has the exact same origin as it is written in the pandas documentation you linked. Look at the minimal example they provided there:

```
def do_something(df):
   foo = df[['bar', 'baz']]  # Is foo a view? A copy? Nobody knows!
   # ... many lines here ...
   foo['quux'] = value       # We don't know whether this will modify df or not!
   return foo
```

The problem is that `foo` might either be a copy of the dataframe `df` or a view. If it is a view, then changes on `foo` will also affect the original dataframe `df`. If `foo` is a copy, then the line `foo['quux'] = value` will have no effect on `df`.

How does this now translate to your problem?

You start with creating a dataframe from a `*.csv` file:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv("IMF and BBG Fair Values.csv")
```

Then you select the columns "IMF_VALUE", "BBG_FV", "IMF_DATE" from the dataframe `raw_data` in the following way:

```
ISO_TH = raw_data[["IMF_VALUE", "BBG_FV", "IMF_DATE"]]
```

Now, this looks very similar to the second line from the documentation:

```
foo = df[['bar', 'baz']]
```

Is your `ISO_TH` a view or a copy of `raw_data`? We don't now! So what happens if we change a column of `ISO_TH`? Does `raw_data` also change or not?  We don't now and hence the warning.

Toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data=pd.DataFrame([[np.inf,22,333,44], [3,4,5,2],[1,2,3,4],[np.inf,0,0,0]],columns=["BBG_FV", "IMF_VALUE", "IMF_DATE", "unused"])
ISO_TH = raw_data[["IMF_VALUE", "BBG_FV", "IMF_DATE"]]
# if we now change ISO_TH, we get a warning
ISO_TH.IMF_VALUE=[0,0,0,0] # SettingWithCopyWarning
```

The fact that you create an intermediate object `filtered_TH` from `ISO_TH` changes nothing here.

How can we solve this? Easy, we read the docs and do what is written there!

```
ISO_TH = raw_data.loc[:,["IMF_VALUE", "BBG_FV", "IMF_DATE"]]
```

And continue as before.

Additional information: [What rules does Pandas use to generate a view vs a copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy)

Comment: Thank you so much - i still get the warning by adding that line after the raw_data reading the csv. Idk why - can I just ignore it?

Comment: If you use my proposed solution then no warning should appear. If you still get warnings, please add a fully functional minimal example to your initial post so that we can see where this warning comes from. With my minimal example, no warning appears on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - replaced my code and used the toy code above and i have no error. The issue for me now is when i Run ISO_TH i get the below data (what happened to my numbers?)

 IMF_VALUE BBG_FV IMF_DATE
0 0 inf 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000333
1 0 3.000000 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005
2 0 1.000000 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003
3 0 inf 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000

Comment: As you can read from the code, I generated some toy data. You would have to replace the line starting with "raw_data=" by your line and load the csv. As I don't have your data, I could not include those.