# Pandas multiindex dataframe .columns not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe:

```
  unique     cat     numerical    
       c   f   b   d         a   e
0      2   5   1   3         0   4
1      8  11   7   9         6  10
2     14  17  13  15        12  16
```

I'm trying to get the column names under `'unique'` and `'cat'`. For just `'unique'` alone, I did:

```
print(df.loc[:,'unique'].columns)
```

yielding:

```
Index(['c', 'f'], dtype='object')
```

Evidently, that works. Then, I tried to it for 2 columns at once:

```
new_df = df.loc[:,['cat','unique']].swaplevel(0,1,1)
print(new_df)
```

yields:

```
       c      f   b   d
  unique unique cat cat
0      2      5   1   3
1      8     11   7   9
2     14     17  13  15
```

So far, so good. But when I try:

```
print(new_df.columns)
```

I get:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['cat', 'numerical', 'unique']],
           labels=[[2, 5, 1, 3], [2, 2, 0, 0]])
```

Which is the same as when printing the columns of the original dataframe. What's going on?

Comment: You are looking at a view of the previous dataframe `df`. See here for a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296545/8146556