# python id()'s function returns different values for the same object

Tags: python, pandas

I don't understand why python's id() function returns different values for an element in a pandas' dataframe

The dataframe looks like this:

```
>>>df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  4  5
2  3  6
```

And the result of the function is the following:

```
>>> id(df.loc[0].A)
140079556632464
>>> id(df.loc[0].A)
140079556632440
>>> id(df.loc[0].A)
140079556632416
>>> id(df.loc[0].A)
140079556632464
>>> id(df.loc[0].A)
140079556632440
>>> id(df.loc[0].A)
140079556632416
```

Shouldn't the function return always the same value? Is this related to some internal implementation of pandas or is it fundamental to python?

Comment: Why should it return the same value? `loc` returns a copy of the data, so the ID will differ each time. If you are seeing recurring IDs in patterns, that means python is cacheing the ID values.

Comment: I don't think so: `.loc`  can return a view or a copy, cf.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy#23296545