# python pandas assignment of missing value as an copy

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to set the mean value of group of products in my dataset (wants to iterate each category and fill the missing data eventually)

```
df.loc[df.iCode == 160610,'oPrice'].fillna(value=df[df.iCode == 160610].oPrice.mean(), inplace=True)
```

it's not working (maybe treating it like a copy)

Thanks

Comment: I'm feeling a `groupby().fillna()` here.

Comment: Good Hint, df.oPrice.fillna(df.groupby(by='iCode').oPrice.transform('mean'), inplace=True) Worked

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc[(df.iCode == 160610) & (df.oPrice.isna()),'oPrice'] = df.loc[df.iCode == 160610].oPrice.mean()`

Comment: Mind adding some explanation of what you're doing here?

Comment: what he is doing is a form of chain indexing.

First indexing `df.loc[df.iCode == 160610,'oPrice']` the next is `isna()`.

by doing `df.loc[(df.iCode == 160610) & (df.oPrice.isna()),'oPrice']` allows you to index the dataframe only once. then explicitly assigning the values to the NAs `oPrice column` with the mean of the `oPrice column`.

read https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296545/11724956 for more details.