# SettingwithcopyWarning: while try to use .sort_values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to sort a dataframe by total column:

```
df.sort_values(by='Total', ascending=False, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

But I'm getting the following warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

When I followed the link it opens up and using `.loc` methods is suggested. But after that I followed the [.sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) where I find out to use `inplace=False` or None.

My question is what if I got a dataframe columns which is not sorted, and if I don't use `inplace=True`, my dataframe will be sorted for further use or I have to assigned a new name to the dataframe and saved it.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, and I don't think inplace = True should do that, but I'm a tyro at this so I hesitate to say it is a bug, it just looks like it to me. I dropped the inplace and instead assigned the dataframe and everything was OK. inplace does support True at the link you gave

Comment: @JulianMoore Agreed. This is a bug in my eyes.

Comment: This error is likely happening because of code that you have before sorting, where you set df to a copy of df. A common example is `df = df[['columnA', 'columnB']]`. If you share previous lines of code, happy to help you with a solution.

Answer (score 7):

The warning isn't clear, but if you use .copy() combined with .loc when you create df by filtering another df then the warning should go away.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'num':range(10),'Total':range(20,30)})
# loc without copy
df_2 = df.loc[df.num <5]

df_2.sort_values(by='Total', ascending=False, axis=0, inplace =True)
# leads to SettingWithCopyWarning

df_3 = df.loc[df.num <5].copy()
df_3.sort_values(by='Total', ascending=False, axis=0, inplace =True)
# no warning
```

You will find some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy) but there is a really annoying class of Pandas bugs that the setting with copy warning is trying to protect you from.

```
df_4 = df.copy()
df_4['new_col'] = df_4.num *2
df_5 = df
df_5['new_col_2'] = df_5.num *3 

# df_5's column is also added to df, but not df_4, because of .copy()
df.columns
#Index(['num', 'Total', 'new_col_2'], dtype='object')

df[df.num <2].loc[:,['Total']] = 100
df.Total.max()
# still 29, because of the chained .locs, Total was not updated.
df.loc[df.num<2,'Total'] = 100
df.Total.max()
# 100
```

Answer (score 3):

Using assignment (rather than inplace) clears the warning for me:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Total', ascending=False, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just avoid the inplace operation and store the sorted dataframe like this:

```
df_cp = df.copy() # optional copy of the original df
df_sort = df_cp.sort_values(by='Total', ascending=False, axis=0)
del df #deleting df if it's not needed
```

I've come across copy warnings that seem like bugs, so currently I prefer avoiding syntax that may trigger them.