# Pythond Pandas Dataframe by reference, but what about .dropna()

Tags: python, dataframe, pointers, reference

I thought I understood that an assignment of a second df works with a reference / pointer. So in the code below the first element changes in 'both' df's. But what happens with .dropna() was unexpected for me. It seems somehow this method creates a copy. Anyone know how this works and why? See the second code part.
I expected the two df's to have changed.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, np.NaN, 2, 3, 5, np.NaN])
df2 = df1
df3 = df1

df2.iloc[0, 0] = 9
#Both changed
display(df1)
display(df2)

df3 = df3.dropna()

#Only df3 changed ??
display(df1)
display(df3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing

```
df2.iloc[0, 0] = 9
```

the operation is inplace. Also, till now, df2 and df3 are copy of df1 and any modification would impact df1.
But when you do

```
df3 = df3.dropna()
```

here df3 is assigned a view of dataframe returned and not a copy. So, as it is a view, there is no impact on df1. But if you would have done the following:

```
df3.dropna(inplace=True)
```

df3 would have been modified inplace and as it is a copy of df1, df1 would also have been changed in same way.
Refer [What rules does Pandas use to generate a view vs a copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy) for details.