# Modifying a DataFrame after two uses of loc

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a big DataFrame and an index array (perhaps obtained via `groupby`). I'd like to create a view into the original DataFrame and modify that view such that the original DataFrame is updated, in the following manner:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=list('ABC'), index=range(1, 9))

subdf = df.loc[[1, 3, 4], :]

subdf.loc[:, 'A'] = 100
```

When I create `subdf = df.loc[[1, 3, 4], :]`, I believe I'm getting a *view* into the original dataframe, as I used `loc`, per my interpretation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296545/500207) and the [technical documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

However, when I attempt to modify `subdf`, I see that changes aren't propagated to `df`, indicating `subdf` was a *copy*, not a *view*.

Now, I recognize I could use the index `[1, 3, 4]` in the original `loc`, i.e., I could achieve this `df.loc[[1, 3, 4], 'A'] = 100`, but I'd like to create a separate variable to contain the view that I can then pass to functions that aren't aware that they're dealing with a subset of the data.

**Questions** Are two chainings of `loc` not guaranteed to return a view? How can I achieve my goal of having a stand-alone variable for the view that I can then modify, and have those modifications reflect in the original?

Comment: I believe this is similar for numpy arrays, a view of a view is not guaranteed a view. The way around it would be `df.loc[subdf.index, 'A']] = 100`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't think that's true, Numpy views of views of views are views: `import numpy as np; x = np.random.rand(5,5); y = x[:3, 2:]; z = y[0]; z[:] = 0` works as expected, updating a corner of the original `x`.

Comment: Yet, doing what you were trying to do with `subdf`: `x = np.random.rand(5,5); y = x[[1,3,4], :]; y[:,0] = 0` doesn't.

Comment: Gotcha! The reason the first Numpy snippet worked is because the sub-array was *contiguous*. As soon as you ask for non-contiguous chunks, it becomes impossible to make a view. Thank you!