# Filling the NaN values in the column dataframe based on condition python pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to update my dataframe column value based on the condition but when i check my data frame its value is not getting updated.

```
for i in titanic['Survived'].unique():
meanAge = titanic.Age[titanic['Survived'] == i].mean()
meanAge = "{:.1f}".format(meanAge)
df = titanic['Survived'] == i
df1 = titanic.Age[df];
df1.fillna(meanAge, inplace=True)
#print (df1) the value seems to be updated here
```

but print(titanic still shows NAN values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that most likely `df1` is a copied object from the dataframe, and it does not reference the `titanic` dataframe.

It will probably help you to do like below (just replace the condition with one that includes NaN values). So instead of calling the method `fillna` just use the assignment operator with the proper index.

```
titanic.Age[titanic['Survived'] == i] = meanAge
```

If you don't have memory constraints is better to think about dataframes as immutable.

Instead of updating in place, try to make a copy of the original and update the new one.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of shallow copy operations, and operations with "inplace" as an argument, [all operations generate a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296545/10843558).

You can directly update the titanic DataFrame after:

```py
for i in titanic['Survived'].unique():
    meanAge = titanic.Age[titanic['Survived'] == i].mean()
    meanAge = "{:.1f}".format(meanAge)
    df = titanic['Survived'] == i
    df1 = titanic.Age[df];
    df1.fillna(meanAge, inplace=True)
    titanic.loc[df, 'Age'] = df1
```